# Passing Objects as Parameters in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass Objects as parameters to the javascript function and

I had tried with the following,Actually iam calling the function the function in innerHtml..

```
var tempObj={
        result:results,
        jsobj:jsObj
    }

    str +='<input type="button" onclick="buildCstrWiseChart('+tempObj+')" value="View" class="btn btn-info">';
```

but this didnt works for me iam getting the error like..

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
[Break On This Error]   

buildCstrWiseChart([object Object])
```

can any one help in this..

Comment: that is valid javascript code and should work, show some more code, i guess your error is somewhere else

Comment: What does `someFunc` do? And how/where are you calling it?

Comment: You will need to post your whole/actual code, especially the part with the list. The syntax error should have a line number for it.

Comment: Are you doing something like `eval("someFunc(" + someObject + ")")`? If so, why?

Comment: You have a syntax error, so all you can do is find it and fix it. Run your code through http://jshint.com if you need help finding it.

Comment: I would have thought the error message should have been clear: `missing ] after element list`. You should be able to trace the line number of the error as well in your browser.

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/g752S/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply members..i just updated the code..iam calling the function in innerHtml

Comment: Now that you've edited the post, it's completely different from the initial code. You're treating an object as a string. That's the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were treating an object as if it were a string. That's the error.

Is `tempObj` a global variable? If so, just do

```
str +='<input type="button" onclick="buildCstrWiseChart(tempObj)" value="View" class="btn btn-info">';`
```

Comment: +1 If it isn't global, OP will need to make it globally accessible to make the object reachable from an inline handler attribute.

Comment: Thanks its working..Initially i tried this..but it didnt works then...yep thats works fine when i declared the variable globally..can i know why to declare that variable as global..

Comment: Like @squint said, your `onclick` handler needs to be aware of what `tempObj` is. So if `tempObj` is not global, the handler would not know what it is. Makes sense?

Comment: @sasi: The function is created in effectively the same way that a function made using the `Function` constructor would be made. This means that the variable scope is limited to the global scope. *(Actually inline handlers have the properties of a couple DOM elements included in the scope as well, but the local function scope is certainly not included)*.

Answer (score 2):

The string representation of an object is just `[object Object]` so when you attempt to concatenate it when building your HTML you end up with

```
onclick="buildCstrWiseChart([object Object])"
```

which isn't valid HTML. The `[object` part is parsed as the start of an array, but the `Object]` part isn't valid array syntax.

I'd suggest, rather than building a HTML string, you instead use jQuery to actually create the DOM element:

```
$('<input type="button"/>', {
    value: 'View',
    className: 'btn btn-info'
}).click(function() {
    buildCstrWiseChart(tempObj);
});
```

Then use either the `.append()` or `.appendTo()` jQuery function to add that element to whatever containing element you want it to be inside of.

Comment: I think this answer deserves some upvotes since the other one is using some pretty bad ways to solve the problem. First: don't declare handlers inline and Second: don't put variables in global scope just because you can't access them. At the very least wrap them in a global object.

Answer (score 0):

NB: OP has changed the code posted since originally posting.

I'd wager the issue is with this:

```
...onclick="buildCstrWiseChart('+tempObj+')"...
```

I don't think that'd work when `tempObj` isn't something other than a string. Seems dangerous to do in any case.

What you'd really need to do is instead of putting the actual object in the string, put in a value that references it (perhaps build a dictionary of id:object) and just include the id as a data-attribute. Then in your onclick method you can look up that attribute, and find the object for the supplied ID.

Comment: You have enough rep to know this isn't an answer. It's a comment merely stating that the given code works.

Comment: "It works for me" isn't exactly an answer to the question, so the downvotes shouldn't come as a surprise.

Comment: "This works fine" is a perfectly acceptable answer when including something along with it that demonstrates it works and therefore can be eliminated as the source of the problem. If the question is "what's wrong with this?" then "nothing" is not a non-answer.

Answer (score -1):

Well, the problem is in your function `someFunc`.

The following example works perfectly fine:

```
var f = function (el){
    alert(el)
};

var x = {a: "hey", b: "ho"};
```

Then

```
f('hi');
f(x);
```

gives no errors.